# invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*[-fpermissive](might be a multi dimensional array problem, not sure)

Tags: c++, char, constants

I am trying to write a code that deletes a word in a array of strings.

this is my whole code

```
int cancella(char v[],int nv,char ele,char vt[]){  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<nv;i++){
    if (strcmp(v[i],ele))!=0;{
     strcpy(vt[j],v[i]);j++
    }
Return j;
}
}

int main()
{
 char a[DIM][L]={"pane","pizza","pasta","cafe","panino","kebab","patatine"};
 char aT[DIM][L];
 int naT,na=7;
 char elem={"kebab"};
 nat= cacella(a,naT,elem,aT);
 cout<<nat;

}
```

How to fix the Error

```
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

(might be a multi dimensional array problem, not sure)

at:

> if (strcmp(v[i],ele))!=0;{

Comment: `tio.cpp:3:9: error: ‘strcmp’ was not declared in this scope`, `tio.cpp:3:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘!=’ token`, `tio.cpp:4:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token`, `tio.cpp:6:1: error: ‘Return’ was not declared in this scope`, `tio.cpp:12:9: error: ‘DIM’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: `char elem={"kebab"};` What were you expecting this line to do, and why?

Comment: What is your loop bound? (Think carefully before answering)

Comment: What does `nat` refer to?

Comment: `if (strcmp(v[i],ele))!=0;{` What is this?

Comment: What is `L`? Are you sure? Is it right? Are you sure?

Comment: Where are your `#include`s? This cannot be your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with this code.

- Incorrect indirect level at many places (for ex. `char ele` instead of `char *ele`).
- Variables used before initialisation (for ex. `naT`; should probably be `na` instead).
- Improper indentation and formatting.

Some suggestions

- Write only a few line at a time and verify that it compile.
- Read error message carefully. If you don't understand it, then see your compiler help.
- Usually, it is easier to fix error at the top first.
- As some errors are dependent on previous errors, compile again after fixing some errors.
- Be careful with punctuation. Compiler care about misplaced parenthesis or semi-colon.
- Read again your course notes or find a good C++ book.